# LaTeX chord making

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning

I'm making a ukulele songbook and i used this code to make chords rise above the text. but it makes a small space before the word (when you put chords above). Do you know how to fix it?

```
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{%
  \makebox[-6pt][c]{%
    \raisebox{22pt}[24pt]{~~{\setlength{}\huge\textbf{#1\hspace{-0.33in}}} }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sometimes it's better to post a full example document, such that users who want to help you can start 'immediately'.

Comment: Do you had a look into the `guitar` package? Perhaps it might help for the ukulele as well.

Comment: Seems is if you have spurious spaces in the `\newcommand` definition. Try adding a `%` immediately after the first `{`, remove the space following the `}}}` and add a `%` at the end of that line. i.e., use `\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\makebox[-6pt][c]{\raisebox{22pt}[24pt]{~~{\setlength{}\huge\textbf{#1\hspace{-0.33in}}}}}}`.

Comment: `\setlength{}\huge` must generate errors? what is it intended to do, you have not specified which length to set or a value?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to do simple chords here are the commands,

```
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{%
  \makebox[-6pt][c]{%
    \raisebox{22pt}[24pt]{~~{\huge\textbf{#1\hspace{-0.33in}}} }
  }
}
```

Then if you write a song like this:

```
\ch{G}.. Mamma take this \ch{D}badge from \ch{Am7}me\\
\ch{G}.. I can't use\ch{D} it any \ch{C}more\\
\ch{G}.. It's getting \ch{D}dark, too dark to \ch{Am7}see\\
\ch{G}.. Feeles like I'm \ch{D}knocking on heaven's \ch{C}door\\
```

It will generate a  result like:

[image]

Comment: Uh, `\setlength{}\huge` becomes `\huge\relax`, so you probably want to remove `\setlength{}` which does nothing (and is wrong).

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry, it was a leftover i forgot.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\@bsphack
  \raisebox{2ex}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\small\bfseries\strut#1}}\nolinebreak
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
\ch{G}.. Mamma take this \ch{D}badge from \ch{Am7}me\\
\ch{G}.. I can't use\ch{D} it any \ch{C}more\\
\ch{G}.. It's getting \ch{D}dark, too dark to \ch{Am7}see\\
\ch{G}.. Feels like I'm \ch{D}knocking on heaven's \ch{C}door\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]